# PHP extension library dependency

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I have an extenal dependency for my PHP extension which I am struggling to compile successfully.  I would like this extension to be a standalone shared object, which as I understand it is the job of `phpize`.  How do I go about compiling this shared PHP extension with an object file `c.o`?

The manual compile for a standalone application would look as follows:

```
gcc -Wall -o php_library main.c c.o
```

and for a shared library:

```
gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o php_library.so main.c c.o
```

I understand that there are macros for adding in shared library dependencies by modifying `config.m4` such as: `PHP_ADD_LIBRARY(pthread,,EXTENSION_SHARED_LIBADD)`, but I'm not sure how to go about adding in my dependency at compile time.  Is there a macro similar to the above for this use case?

It is worth noting that I do not have access to the depdency code, so `c.o` cannot be modified to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, you have an object file `c.o` which was not compiled to have position-independent code (i.e. `-fPIC` option) that you want to link into your PHP extension. In this case you must static link it alongside the extension code and any shared libraries. There are a couple ways to do this in the `config.m4` file.

The first is to set `CFLAGS` to pass the name of the object code file to the linker like so:

```
CFLAGS=-Wl,c.o
```

The second is to modify `LDFLAGS`:

```
LDFLAGS=c.o
```

When I try the second one I get the following warning during compilation:

```
*** Warning: Linking the shared library testbed.la against the non-libtool
*** objects  c.o is not portable!
```

Everything works either way so I'm not sure what's up with the warning. But the first method doesn't generate the warning.

Here's a complete sample `config.m4`:

```
PHP_ARG_ENABLE(testbed, whether to enable testbed support,
[ --enable-testbed   Enable testbed support])

if test "$PHP_TESTBED" = "yes"; then
  AC_DEFINE(HAVE_TESTBED, 1, [Whether you have testbed support])
  PHP_NEW_EXTENSION(testbed, testbed.c, $ext_shared)
  #LDFLAGS=c.o
  CFLAGS=-Wl,c.o
fi
```

I hope this answers the question.